# How to add react with typescript to an angular js existing project?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, typescript, webpack, runtime-error

```
{
    test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: [/src\/lib/, /node_modules/],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { cacheDirectory: true },
      },
    ],
  },
```

This is the code in webpack.config file. What should be changes done that I can see runtime typescript errors for the new react component (with TSX extention) injected to angular js project (without typescript).        react component is injected using this package.
https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular